# Historic + actual value in the same query?

Tags: hana, history-tables

I was trying to understand how history tables work in HANA.

I have a query whether the following requirement can be achieved using history table.

Suppose, I've a table which maintains site and article wise STOCK.
The STOCK gets updated according to the change in inventory.

Now, if I want the current as well as the previous picture of site-article wise stock can I use the history table for same.
I created a history table and inserted a row in it which gives output :

```
SELECT site,article,stock FROM PH_STOCK_HISTORY AS OF utctimestamp '2019-05-22 12:36:17.909';
```

[image]

I updated the stock and re-run the query :

```
SELECT site,article,stock FROM PH_STOCK_HISTORY AS OF utctimestamp '2019-05-22 12:37:38.55'
```

[image]

Now, I want to get the earlier and the current picture of my stock in the same query.

Is that feasible to achieve this ?

Comment: If you’re on HANA 2 you really should use the system-versioned tables (or the user-time tables) for this scenario. HANA history tables have been long shown to be inefficiently implemented and awkward to operate. The new **temporal** (not temporary) tables are much easier to deal with and a lot more efficient to use.

Comment: Thankyou Lars.
We are on HANA SPS12. I don't think I can use the system-versioned tables functionality in this version of Sap Hana.

Comment: In that case, it's still better to implement the timestamping manually (i.e. add extra timestamp columns and populate them when data changes). The limitations and constraints for history tables are just not worth putting in any effort. SAP itself withdrew the usage of this feature from SAP Business Warehouse when it became clear that the feature is little more than a by-product of the column store (back then, they reimplemented the SAP BW Data Store Object DSO).

Comment: Also: please, make sure to upgrade to HANA 2 soonish. There are only a few functions that are not available and all development is happening on HANA 2.

Answer (score -1):

May be you can achieve this by Union query.

```
    SELECT site,article,stock FROM PH_STOCK_HISTORY AS OF utctimestamp '2019-05-22 12:36:17.909'
    union 
    SELECT site,article,stock FROM PH_STOCK_HISTORY AS OF now();
```

Try this :)

Comment: That’s exactly not how history tables work. With the newer temporal tables of HANA2 that would be possible (though unnecessary).